# Error when using stl function

Tags: r, stl

I want to do seasonal decomposition in R for my data. Load file from csv

My data:

```
sls

        Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul       Aug       Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec    
1 11785,83  12101,4   12729,47  7198,66   14042,85  7495,98   4222,16   3852,25   10450,39  12654,14  11691,48  14297,55     
2 9722,62   15880,03  13892,46  9751,58   9324,29   13163,32  10943,64  16667,45  12804,18  15208,94  11232,16  28429,99     
3 11774,15  17190,94  47000,96  40253,19  46600,64  41572,79  51292,2   57010,61  44387,04  75025,1   53726,59  46351,99     
4 55370,3   79487,03  69863,94  59221,7   44417,79  58246,06  67817,03  65453,26  81489,82  79847,22  76656,37  108148,16    
5 84953,01  49113,57  61827,4   62403,33  59764,03  49132,28  70985,93  89076,76  95678,61  70352,35  71657,23  55003,81     
6 60275,36  148138,33 104608,67 72627,44  75075,51  90502,9   96765,18  93158,7   148888,08 122182,75 92549,97  131436,32    
7 2168,21   961,7     1477,2    2860,2    2256,07   2996,4    2072,95   2587,8    1969,3     

class(sls)
# [1] "ts"

dim(sls)
# NULL
```

I got error after using `stl` function

```
stl(sls, s.window="periodic")
Ошибка в stl(sls, s.window = "periodic") :
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

What I have to do to fix the problem?

Comment: Can you use `dput` results on your data frame so it is easier to load.  That would help troubleshoot.

Comment: What is the output of `options("OutDec")`?

Comment: You are asking for help but your are not really responsive to requests. Voting to close.

Comment: Ive used "dput"


structure(c("11785,83", ***, .Tsp = c(1, 
7.66666666666667, 12), class = "ts")


"***" are other numbers. Cut it because too long for post

Comment: options("OutDec")
$OutDec
[1] "."

Comment: Post in you question not in a comment. And there is a discrepancy between your default decimal `"."` and the decimal of your data `","`.